# Java JCE Encrypt Folders?

Tags: java, encryption, jce

Is it possible to encrypt entire folders with Java's JCE library. The folders will contain other folders/files if that is a problem. For those who don't know what JCE is, it stands for Java Cryptography Extension and it is used for encryption in Java.

Comment: You could ZIP the folders and then encrypt that data?

Comment: But is it possible to just encrypt the folder? If I have to encrypt a zip its another step in the decrypting process to access the zip.

Answer (score 4):

No.  You can't encrypt entire folders with only Java's JCE library.  It's not hard to zip it first though using a stream wrapper like [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and [`ZipOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html).  Since you don't care about file size reduction, you could also use [`jtar`](https://code.google.com/p/jtar/).  That will make it easy to tar up the folder after which it can be encrypted with JCE like any other file.

I would make a class called something like `public class FolderEncrypter` with methods `public byte[] encryptFolder(File folder)` and `public File decryptFolder(public byte[])`.  Then it is easy to reuse throughout your code whenever you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I have another quick question about JCE, you can encrypt .png's and .ogg files right? They are just files and not folders/zips

Comment: @ExoNaut You can encrypt anything that you can express as a byte array. So yes, PNGs and OGGs are fine.

Comment: Your suggested method signatures don't look right to me. `encryptFolder` should return a `byte[]` and `decryptFolder` should accept a `byte[]` as a parameter.

Comment: @DuncanJones I agree and I made the change.  I was thinking that the method would encrypt the file in place and return a reference to the new File, but it would be better design to let the calling code do what they want with it.